# Use WinForms custom textBox in WPF?

Tags: winforms, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application that is in need of syntax highlighting. [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/FastColoredTextBox_.aspx?q=C#%20code%20highlight#_articleTop) is *exactly* what I'm looking for... however its for WinForms. Can I, and if so, how do I add it to my WPF program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wpfsyntax.codeplex.com/

http://devhawk.net/2009/07/09/syntax-highlighting-textboxes-in-wpf-a-sad-story/

Answer (score 1):

There's a [walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944.aspx)

> This walkthrough steps you through an application that hosts a Windows Forms composite control to perform data entry in a WPF application. The composite control is packaged in a DLL. This general procedure can be extended to more complex applications and controls.

In this scenario the WinForms controls are in a separate dll which needs to be signed.

The WPF application needs to use a [WinFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) control as the container for the control.